# PHP Youtube API: Search videos with specific language

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am using zend to search videos on youtube. My question is, is there a way to limit the results to english only videos? Here is what I have so far code wise:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setOrderBy('viewCount');
$query->setSafeSearch('none');
$query->setVideoQuery($keyword);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can search by language, but you can search by RegionId (or RegionCode in v3).  Depending on the use case, it may be good enough to pass in all English speaking countries and filter that way.